# OAUTH logout and Oauth Token Validation

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring oath to secure my RESP API's and successfully generated the oauth token. Now I am stuck in 2 place mentioned below.

1) **Logout:** I didn't find any URL in specification which I can call to logout/invalidate the token. One option I got is to write own implementation of logout and delete the token from the token store from that method. But is there any other way to logout/invalidate the token like we retrieve the token.

2) **Validation of Token**:   Is there any url where I can pass my token and can validate that the token is valid or not. One way is to write a own method from which I will validate token. If own method returns 200 then valid token else invalid token(401). But like to know that , is Spring OAUth provide any such url.

Comment: What token store(jdbc,inmemory,jwt) are you using? if let say JwtTokenStore, then it never persists tokens and hitting just logout default url on client side and then on success, redirect to authorization server logout url and handle the successful logout  and redirect to client back. As for validation of token . /oauth/check_token endpoint can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The most common usage is to integrate Spring security with a standards based cloud authorization server, in which case you can use these options:

- Logout occurs when a UI calls the [End Session Endpoint](https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api/logout)
- Tokens can be validated by APIs either in memory or via an [Introspection Endpoint](https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api/token-introspection)

Note however that not all Authorization Servers implement these endpoints in a standard way.

Deleting tokens on logout is the most standard option, along with keeping tokens short lived so that they expire soon anyway.